# Conditional formatting based on number of characters

Tags: google-sheets, conditional-formatting

In Google Spreadsheets, is there a way to conditionally format a cell if it has more than 30 characters?

Answer (score 13):

Yes! Highlight the cells you want to format. Go to Format > Conditional Formatting.

Once you're in the conditional formatting dialog, choose "Custom Formula Is" from the select box (it's the last option). In the text field type:

```
=len(XY)>30
```

X will be the column you're in and Y will be the row you want it to start at. So if you want to check the entire column A starting at row 4, your formula would look like this:

```
=len(A4)>30
```

Then just assign a background color/text color. If you have selected an entire row, you will need to adjust the range if you've got a couple of heading cells. In my case, I selected the entire column but I only wanted to check starting at A4 and continuing to the last row in the column. In this example, the range then should be A4:A.

Here's a screenshot of what I had:

[image: Screenshot of the conditional formatting dialog with instructions on how to conditionally format strings that are longer than X characters]

And here's how the data looks after clicking "save rules":

[image: Formatted strings.]

I added a second column in there that counts the length of the string. That was just as simple as highlighting the column and adding a function to each cell:

```
=LEN(A1)
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: Don't forget the = at the start of the custom formula. I was trying just "LEN($A1) > 10" and it wasn't working, until I put the equals sign in!

Answer (score 2):

Not on the cell itself, without the usage of Google Apps Script. Adding a helper column will allow you get realy close:
[image]

`A1` and `A4` both have more than 30 characters. Set the whole column to have a conditional format like this:
[image]

Now add the following formula in `B1`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(LEN(FILTER(A:A;A:A<>""))>30)
```

This will check column A, whether the entry has more than 30 characters and will return TRUE or FALSE.

See example file I've prepared: [more than 30 characters](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0ApDwwZxW-IBcdHhvWUxuNF8yYi01cHlueUNZNEUzNHc&usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

To make sure you don't have to do this for each cell separately, you can play with the range function:

To format cell A1 if the length of the text in it is longer than 100 chars:

Google Sheets menu → *Format* → *Conditional Formatting*

```
=LEN(A1)>100         //or: =LEN(A1:A1)>100
```

In the range field:

```
A1:A1
```

Set the colour as you wish.

Simply pull the cell down to let this rule apply to other cells in column A!

Answer (score 0):

If your cell is A1, in New Google Sheets, in Custom formula is please try:

```
=len(A1)>30 withRange: `A1` and the formatting of your choice.
```